# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: PItable.id

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to using django to read from an existing database, 'p.n.db', it already has 100 rows data. I put 'p.n.db' in the directory as manage.py.  The settings.py look like

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
},
'chinookdb': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'p.n.db'),
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
}}
```

I run

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database=chinookdb > chinook/models.py
```

It created the models.py

```
class Pitable(models.Model):
pid = models.TextField(db_column='PID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
lname = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
fname = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
affs = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
pmidlist = models.TextField(db_column='PMIDlist', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
clustering = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'PItable'
```

Then I run

```
python manage.py makemigrations chinook
python manage.py migrate
```

Then I runserver to access the table in p.n.db, it gives the error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: PItable.id
```

Thanks for any help! My goal is to use django to read from an existing database.

Comment: The problem may be that you haven't designated any fields as a primary key, therefore Django defaults to a column named `ID` as the primary key.

Comment: I changed pid field as a primary key. It works now. Many thanks!!